# Function returns nonetype when dividing input into fractional number

Tags: python

I'm trying to output the value of this function:

```
def function(A,Z):
      if (A % 2 == 0 and Z % 2 == 0):
          return a_1*A - a_2*A**(2/3) - a_3*(Z**2/A**(1/3)) - a_4* ((A - 2*Z)**2/A) + 
          a_5_2/np.sqrt(A)                                                                    
      if (A % 2 == 1):
          return a_1*A - a_2*A**(2/3) - a_3*(Z**2/A**(1/3)) - a_4* ((A - 2*Z)**2/A)
      if (A % 2 == 0 and Z % 2 == 1):
          return a_1*A - a_2*A**(2/3) - a_3*(Z**2/A**(1/3)) - a_4* ((A - 2*Z)**2/A) + 
          a_5_3/np.sqrt(A)
```

Into an array, and the grab the max value from that array. For a fixed Z.

```
  def getMaximumEnergy(Z, i):
      values = []
      for x in range(1,i):
          values.append(function(x,Z))
      maxEnergy = max(values)
      print("The maximum energy is:",maxEnergy)
      return maxEnergy
```

This compiles and runs as expected, but I'd like to use fractional arguments to the function method:

```
values.append(function(x/10,Z))
```

However, this returns:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Why does it not just output a float?

Comment: If none of your `if` conditions are true, the function never executes a `return` statement - and therefore implicitly returns None.  Basically, the function is only meaningful with integer inputs.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, that is it.